# I need to log out of .NET Core app without requiring a button-click

Tags: .net-core, identity, logout

I have a .NET Core app using Identity and under certain conditions, I need to be able to programmatically log a user out. That user may have multiple active sessions and I only want to log them out of one, so I can **not** use;

```
await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user)
```

Here is what I've tried - in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie();
```

In a controller

```
public async Task Logout()
{
    await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Identity.Application");
    Response.Redirect("~/Identity/Account/Login");
    return;
}
```

Run locally it does exactly what I want: it navigates to the login screen and won't let me access any other pages (by entering a URL or clicking the back-arrow).

Published to Azure it doesn't log me out: it routes me to the login screen, but from there I can click the back-arrow, or type in the URL of any page in the app and it brings me to it - so I'm not logged out.

Any help is appreciated.